Sending a JSON as value to text key in Slack's api
I am using the end-point https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage
My messages arrive fine as long as my payload is something simple as
{
"channel":"#brainstorming",
"text":"Useless Text"
}

But I need to send a proper well formatted JSON payload that I want to appear. I am OK if it appears as a code block or something. But I want the proper JSON which I have a python dictionary. Converting python dictionary and trying to send it as value to text also fails. I spent 4 hours on this and not sure how to do it. Slack's documentation on this is not that helpful

So, I normally push my payloads from an event or through Ansible (python backend). Here's a simple and a more complex format.
Example 1 -
Simple format to a webhook that's tied to 1 channel:
  body: 
    text: >-
      ```{
        "display_information": {
            "name": "Github",
            "description": "Github Actions",
            "background_color": "#364c8a",
            "long_description": "Incoming webhook for Github action notifications"
        },
        "features": {
            "bot_user": {
                "display_name": "Github",
                "always_online": false
            }
        },
        "oauth_config": {
            "scopes": {
                "bot": [
                    "incoming-webhook"
                ]
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "org_deploy_enabled": false,
            "socket_mode_enabled": false,
            "token_rotation_enabled": false
        }
      }```

This results in the following:


Example 2 -
The 2nd one is more configurable, but the JSON isn't beautified.
In this one, since I can't use double-quotes to encapsulate the string, I'm using single-quotes.
  body: 
    channel: "{{ slack_channel_id }}"
    user: "{{ slack_uid }}"
    blocks: [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "text": {
          "type": "plain_text",
          "text": "{{ title_text }}"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": '```{ "display_information": {
                  "name": "Github",
                  "description": "Github Actions",
                  "background_color": "#364c8a",
                  "long_description": "Incoming webhook for Github action notifications"
              },
              "features": {
                  "bot_user": {
                      "display_name": "Github",
                      "always_online": false
                  }
              },
              "oauth_config": {
                  "scopes": {
                      "bot": [
                          "incoming-webhook"
                      ]
                  }
              },
              "settings": {
                  "org_deploy_enabled": false,
                  "socket_mode_enabled": false,
                  "token_rotation_enabled": false
              }
            }```'
        }
      }
    ]

Resulting in the following, which is still correctly formatted, but less pretty:


For reference, Try out the builder-kit on Slack:

I am not sure but did you used json.dump() from json lib to convert the python dic into (serilizable object)a correct json format and then sending it to the endpoint?
It comes with "indent" argument which kinda improve the readability.
import json
json_str=json.dump(your_dic,indent=4)


I'm not a Python developer but in ruby when we have a Hash like: { name: "pedro", age: 27 } we can call the method: .to_json, and this will return a JSON string like: "{\"name\":\"pedro\",\"age\":27}".
I think that if you follow this pattern of formatting your JSON, scaping the special chars you may be good to go. But as I said I don't know how to do it with Python as great as we do in Ruby.
